# server freezes doing post request in index.php laravel

Tags: laravel, curl, post

I'm trying to get some data from my database through an api I made in Laravel. The api works fine and returns data like expected in my controllers. When I try to post in the index.php (on top of the page) of a laravel project the server freezes and I get no error.

The same code runs perfect in my controllers without the server freezing.

What is the difference between these files causing this error?

```
    $Authorization = 'samplesample';

    $data = array(
        'app_key' => 'appkey123'
    );

    $payload = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'localhost:80/api/getModulerSettings');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: $Authorization"] );

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: What do you mean by server freezes? Are you sure you're getting no errors at all? Have you checked laravel log and nignx logs?

Comment: No errors in Laravel log. This is the error in apache (localhost) Apache server interrupted...
018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11848:tid 520] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 11 11:36:30.452745 2018] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 11848:tid 2672] AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting

Comment: Seems pretty clear what the problem is. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild